# Instance of a ViewController gives error "found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I am trying to load MyChatController in another controller with Swift 2. This code works finely in Swift 1.2 but after updating to Xcode 7 my app is crashing with the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Does any one know how to fix this problem in Swift 2?

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let chatController: MyChatController = MyChatController()

    chatController.opponentImage = UIImage(named: "User")
    chatController.title = "My Chat"

    let helloWorld = ChatMessage(content: "Hello....!!", sentBy: .User)
    chatController.messages = [helloWorld]
    chatController.delegate = self
    chatController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatController, animated: false)

  }
```

Comment: Not sure but You can try with this syntax for your   let chatController: MyChatController = MyChatController()! self.navigationController!.pushViewController(chatController, animated: false)

Comment: on what line exactly this is happening?

Comment: Yeh i had tried all possible ways but its not working..@mrunal thanki

Comment: @Nishant at this line error is fired let chatController: MyChatController = MyChatController()

Comment: So MyChatController() is returning nil, then? We'll probably need to see the source for that.

Comment: here you can see the source code of MyChatController https://github.com/PrincessMine/MyChatController

Comment: How did you initialize your controller with `MyChatController()`? There is no `init()` in your source code. You should instantiate controller with `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` or using `UIViewController` initializers.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through your code. 
There is a mistake. Please go through the following steps.

1. Go to a method called align in StretchyTextView.
2. In this method your trying to unwrap nil (self.selectedTextRange?.end)!. Initially selectedTextRange would be nil.
3. So in the beginning of the method return if self.selectedTextRange is nil.

   func align() {

   ```
   if self.selectedTextRange == nil {
       return
   }

   let caretRect: CGRect = self.caretRectForPosition(self.selectedTextRange!.end)

   let topOfLine = CGRectGetMinY(caretRect)
   let bottomOfLine = CGRectGetMaxY(caretRect)

   let contentOffsetTop = self.contentOffset.y
   let bottomOfVisibleTextArea = contentOffsetTop + CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)

   /*
   If the caretHeight and the inset padding is greater than the total bounds then we are on the first line and aligning will cause bouncing.
   */

   let caretHeightPlusInsets = CGRectGetHeight(caretRect) + self.textContainerInset.top + self.textContainerInset.bottom
   if caretHeightPlusInsets < CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) {
       var overflow: CGFloat = 0.0
       if topOfLine < contentOffsetTop + self.textContainerInset.top {
           overflow = topOfLine - contentOffsetTop - self.textContainerInset.top
       } else if bottomOfLine > bottomOfVisibleTextArea - self.textContainerInset.bottom {
           overflow = (bottomOfLine - bottomOfVisibleTextArea) + self.textContainerInset.bottom
       }
       self.contentOffset.y += overflow
   }
   ```

   }